# Ubuntu 18.04 Server - setting DNS With Network Bridge

Tags: networking, dns, network-bridge

I am trying to configure my Ubuntu 18.04 server's network which uses a bridge because it also acts as a KVM host. Unfortunately I can't seem to get the DNS to work when the bridge configuration is in effect. Here is the file in its current form:

```
# ifupdown has been replaced by netplan(5) on this system.  See
# /etc/netplan for current configuration.
# To re-enable ifupdown on this system, you can run:
#    sudo apt install ifupdown
#
#
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# Section 1
#auto enp30s0
#iface enp30s0 inet static
#       address 10.1.0.236
#       netmask 255.248.0.0
#       gateway 10.0.0.1
#       dns-nameservers 10.1.0.2

# Section 2
# The primary network interface
auto enp30s0
iface enp30s0 inet manual
        dns-nameservers 10.1.0.2

auto kvmbr0
iface kvmbr0 inet static
        address 10.1.0.236
        netmask 255.248.0.0
        gateway 10.0.0.1
        bridge_ports enp30s0
        bridge_stp off
        bridge_fd 0
        bridge_maxwait 0
```

If I comment out section2 and uncomment section 1, the server seems  to work just fine. However, I can't seem to get the dns working with section 2 no matter what I try, with moving the dns-nameservers line to both the enp30s0 or the kvmbr0 section (or both).

It is worth noting that I have already run `sudo apt install ifupdown`.